# The time could slip

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

Is the following grammatical and idiomatic? What I want to say is that the meeting is supposed to hold until 3pm, but it can go off time, like to 4pm.

> Although the meeting is scheduled to be ended on 3pm, there could be a
>   slip of time.

Answer (score 1):

"The time could slip" is quite normal and idiomatic, but "there could be a slip of time" sounds more like dialogue from a bad science-fiction movie.

Also, "scheduled to end at 3pm" would be more idiomatic than "scheduled to be ended on 3pm".

Overall, my most natural (Br.Eng) tweaking of your sentence would be

> Although the meeting is scheduled to end at 3pm, that time could slip.